# Is is possible to make a non-rooted Huawei U8110 (T-Mobile Pulse Mini) recognisable by the `adb devices` command on OS X?

Tags: adb, huawei

Currently, on OS X 10.6.8 Snow Leopard, this is all I get, even with USB debugging enabled on the phone:

```
$ ./adb devices
List of devices attached 

$
```

The phone shows up under About This Mac, and its SD card mounts and unmounts perfectly on command. I have tried several USB cables.

Comment: Have you set the correct udev rules?

Comment: I don't think udev exists on OS X. See http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/46954 for instance.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439379/android-development-on-win-7-64-bit-with-pulse-mini-huawei